# Отслеживание вызова в стороннем приложении

Tags: java

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то отследить вызов метода скомпилированного класса (стороннего приложения) и, соответственно, выполнить при этом какое-либо действие.

Answer (score 1):

разумеется.

есть дебаггеры (для десктопа - вроде jdb, для android - smalidea, или baksmali старых версий + eclipse, или Krakatau, или Soot), у них есть исходный код, где-то и API какие-то - помучавшись, можно разобраться, как туда добавить что-то свое.

и есть готовые либы вроде MSHookFunction (cydia)